# iOS how to sync data from inhouse app with pc?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-data

**Quick summary**: I am looking for a way to automatically sync data over cable from my app with a map on my computer.

**Context**:
I have a selfmade iOS app which I use as a tool during guided tours. This app is installed on 40 iPads and displays pictures and movies on demand. The content has to be updated frequently and since this takes a lot of time (40x 4Gb on average), I am searching for an automated process.

**The original idea** was to let the app search for files in the iTunes directory, but it turns out that iTunes changes the names of synced files. A file named image.png will become IMG99938.png after syncing: not helpfull at all. Syncing with a server over wifi isn't a solution either, as no (affordable) network can transfer that amount of data to and from 40 clients without errors.

**I am currently** syncing the content of my app by mounting it as a drive with iExplorer, than syncing this drive with a map on my MacBook. This process requires 3 different software packages, is not very stable and is limited to sync the iPads one-by-one.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance and with kind regards,
Laurens